# Showing Popover in a Table element using Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, popover

Can anyone explain how to use popover on a table element using Codeigniter?

```
<td> <span id="popover" data-toggle="popover" data-content="<?php echo $userData[$i]->name; ?>"></span><?php echo custom_echo($userData[$i]->name,15); ?></td>
```

And javascript code is

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#popover").popover({
      html: true,
      animation: false,
      placement: "bottom"
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: fix grammar, formatting, remove cruft

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is not working?

Using your code, I have guessed how output `html` would look like:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><span id="popover" data-toggle="popover" data-content="user name in popover">user name in span</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I have also added your script in `onLoad` event:

```
 $("#popover").popover({
                html: true,
                animation: false,
                placement: "bottom"
            });
```

I have included some resources:

- jQuery
- bootstrap.min.js
- bootstrap.min.css

And it all works fine, as you can see in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d2k8zzsw/1/

Comment: i follow exactly the same pattern and i include jquery 1.11.2 and bootstrap also but it doesnot work in my side

Comment: i am on local server how can i show you my html page please help??

Comment: In browser, right click -> View page source. It will open up page source in new tab. Copy that over here. If content is too big, you can also paste it into http://pastebin.com/ and share the link.

Comment: i succeed to run popover but now the problem is that it shows only first element in a popover but the table consists of 5 elements it does not work in loop